# AdStock transformation implementation using both approaches: geometric decay and delayed decay for weight function

Tags: r, model

I'm trying to replicate the approach of applying Adstock transformations (to capture Carryover effect) using 2 functions described here: https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/46001.pdf

So there are 2 formulas for geometric and delayed adstock (see page 3 of the research paper mentioned above). The code I use is the following:

```
geom_decay    <- function(rate,l,...) sum((rate^l) *...) / sum(rate^l)

delayed_decay <- function(rate,l,theta,...){
  sum((rate^((l-theta)^2)) *...) / sum(rate^(l-theta)^2)
}



# generate demo data
set.seed(1)
n <- 52 * 2 # number of data points
t <- seq(0, 4*pi, length.out = n)
b <- 8 # essentially the number of pillars in a year
c.norm1 <- rnorm(n,0,0.5)
amp <- 2
week <- seq(1:104)

x <- abs(1*sin(b*t)+c.norm1*amp) #simulated media variable

#scale the media variable:

x=x/max(x)


#x <- seq(0,1, length.out = 100) 
date <- seq(from = as.Date("2018-01-01"), length.out = 104, by = "1 week")
L = 13 #2
x<- x %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  add_column(date) %>%
  rename(x = value)



x_gd=x %>%
  tq_mutate(select = x, mutate_fun = rollapply, width = L, align = "right",
            FUN = geom_decay,
            #function args
            rate = 0.9,
            l = seq(from = L-1 , to = 0),
            #ts_mutate
            col_rename = "adstock_geometric_decay"
  )
x_gd=x_gd$adstock_geometric_decay



x_dd=x %>%
  tq_mutate(select = x, mutate_fun = rollapply, width = L, align = "right",
            FUN = delayed_decay,
            #function args
            rate = 0.9 , # rate of 0.4 to 0.8 is sensible
            theta =  3,   # theta should be about 1 to 3
            l = seq(from = L-1 , to = 0),
            #ts_mutate
            col_rename = "adstock_delayed_decay"
  )
x_dd=x_dd$adstock_delayed_decay


x = add_column(x,x_dd)

x = add_column(x,x_gd)

view (x)


is.null(x)

x[is.na(x)]<-0


x %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = x, color = "raw media")) +
  geom_line(aes(y =x_gd, color = "adstock_geometric_decay")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = x_dd, color = "adstock_delayed_decay")) +
  theme_ipsum()
```

I need help to build a function to find an optimum delayed adstock for this case.